How to choose a textbook that is pedagogically optimal for oneself?
I am currently using the Russian textbook Mathematical Analysis by Zorich. But the more I use it, the more I feel it is making problems too hard or too advanced for the subject and it is unnecessary. For example, in Zorich's book, he often asks for proof of limited cases from, but not limited to: Numerical Analysis and Differential Geometry. I feel like doing this is utterly unnecessary, and I feel this might be associated with the political background back from the Soviet era. Thus, I feel I could definitely use better textbooks and not waste time on problems that are so unnecessarily hard. Do you agree with my point that problems that are too hard is not the optimal way of learning and teaching? What is, in your opinion, the most pedagogically sound way of writing a textbook? And most importantly, how can you choose a textbook that is pedagogically optimal for oneself?

Is this in the context of studying without an instructor, so just using one or more books?

Yes, I am a homeschooling high school student. @JW

I guess optimal may be subjetive: differenet people woul find the same textbook optimal a, suboptimsl and non optimal. is there an universal criteria? It seema it doess not.

Do you agree with my point that problems that are too hard is not the optimal way of learning and teaching?
Yes.
A lot of people fall into the trap of thinking that to train up their math skills, they should be focusing on the hardest problem types where they think really hard, struggle for a while, and eventually solve it or look up the answer. These problems can be fun (for a certain type of person) but they're not an efficient way to learn.
Approaching challenging problems without having the foundational skills down pat is like jumping into a game of basketball without having developed dribbling and shooting skills. It might feel fun but you're just going to be whiffing every shot and getting the ball stolen from you. You might make one layup the entire game & feel good about it, but that's barely any training volume.
It’s like going to the gym to lift weights but only eeking out a single rep over the entire course of your workout. You need to be banging out more reps if you want to get stronger, and the only way you can bang out those reps is by working with a level of weight that's appropriate for you.
Math is the same way. In an hour-long session, you're going to make a lot more progress by solving 30 problems that each take 2 minutes given your current level of knowledge, than by attempting a single competition problem that you struggle with for an hour. (This assumes those 30 problems are grouped into minimal effective doses, well-scaffolded & increasing in difficulty, across a variety of topics at the edge of your knowledge.)
Now, I'm not saying that challenge problems are bad. I'm just saying that they're not a good use of time until you've developed the foundational skills that are necessary to grapple with these problems in a productive and timely fashion.
Some References
I should point out that while I've made heavy use of analogies here, this is all grounded in decades of research into the cognitive science of learning.
One key empirical result is the expertise reversal effect, a well-replicated phenomenon that instructional techniques that promote the most learning in experts, promote the least learning in beginners, and vice versa. It's true that many highly skilled professionals spend a lot of time solving open-ended problems, and in the process, discovering new knowledge as opposed to obtaining it through direct instruction. But that doesn't mean beginners should do the same. The expertise reversal effect suggests the opposite – that beginners (i.e., students) learn most effectively through direct instruction.
Additionally (and relatedly), there's a mountain of empirical evidence that you can increase the number of examples & problem-solving experiences in a student's knowledge base – but a lack of evidence that you can increase the student’s ability to generalize from those examples (by doing things other than equipping them with progressively more advanced examples & problem-solving experiences).
In other words, research indicates the best way to improve your problem-solving ability in any domain is simply by acquiring more foundational skills in that domain. The way you increase your ability to make mental leaps is not by learning to jump further, but by building bridges.
So, there does not seem to be any tangible, empirically-supported reason to struggle with a challenge problem for a long period of time, when you consider that you could be making more educational progress using that time to learn more content. For instance, in an hour-long session, you're going to make a lot more progress by solving 30 problems that each take 2 minutes given your current level of knowledge, than by attempting a single competition problem that you struggle with for an hour. (This assumes those 30 problems are grouped into minimal effective doses, well-scaffolded & increasing in difficulty, across a variety of topics at the edge of your knowledge.)
(Note: When I say "2 minute problems" I don't mean that as a hard cap. I just mean that you come into the problem with enough background knowledge that you can work 100% productively to complete it in a minimal amount of time. For low-level high school math courses, the minimal amount of time might be lower for many problems, like 1 minute or less. For more theoretical courses in late undergrad, the minimal amount of time might rise to, say, 5-10 minutes for some problems. But I can't imagine a scenario in which a student spends a full hour on a non-research problem while working productively the whole time, unless the solution itself is commensurately long -- e.g., the solution requires writing a chunk of code to implement an algorithm, or there's a proof that requires many cases/sub-proofs, or there are otherwise many different parts to the problem that require solving.)
As Sweller, Clark, and Kirschner sum it up in their 2010 article Teaching General Problem-Solving Skills Is Not a Substitute for, or a Viable Addition to, Teaching Mathematics:

"Although some mathematicians, in the absence of adequate instruction, may have learned to solve mathematics problems by discovering solutions without explicit guidance, this approach was never the most effective or efficient way to learn mathematics. ... In short, the research suggests that we can teach aspiring mathematicians to be effective problem solvers only by providing them with a large store of domain-specific schemas. Mathematical problem-solving skill is acquired through a large number of specific mathematical problem-solving strategies relevant to particular problems. There are no separate, general problem-solving strategies that can be learned."

Another good reference is Putting Students on the Path to Learning: The Case for Fully Guided Instruction by the same authors in 2012. (It's like an expanded version of the 2010 article.)
What is in your opinion the most pedagogically sound way of writing a textbook? And most importantly, how can you choose a textbook that is pedagogically optimal for oneself?
I don't have a long checklist of highly-specific things to do or look for, but I can tell you the underlying principle that it all boils down to: deliberate practice.
In the field of talent development, there is absolutely no debate about the most superior form of training. It's deliberate practice: mindful repetition on performance tasks just beyond the edge of one's capabilities.
Deliberate practice is about making performance-improving adjustments on every single repetition. Any individual adjustment is small and yields a small improvement in performance – but when you compound these small changes over a massive number of action-feedback-adjustment cycles, you end up with massive changes and massive gains in performance.
Deliberate practice is superior to all other forms of training. That is a "solved problem" in the academic field of talent development. It might as well be a law of physics. There is a mountain of research supporting the conclusion that the volume of accumulated deliberate practice is the single biggest factor responsible for individual differences in performance among elite performers across a wide variety of talent domains. (The next biggest factor is genetics, and the relative contributions of deliberate practice vs genetics can can vary significantly across talent domains.)
So, how can you write or find a textbook that implements deliberate practice?
What you need to do is avoid the two failure modes -- that is, cutting corners on either of the two key attributes of deliberate practice ("mindful" and "repetition").
Deliberate practice is not mindless repetition. If you're doing the same thing over and over again, then you're doing deliberate practice wrong. Deliberate practice is about making performance-improving adjustments on every single repetition. Any individual adjustment is small and yields a small improvement in performance, but when you compound these small changes over a massive number of cycles, you end up with massive changes and massive gains in performance. None of this happens if you're mindlessly doing the same thing over and over again without making adjustments.
Likewise, even if you're mindful during practice, you can't skimp on repetition and still call it "deliberate practice." Deliberate practice necessitates a high volume of action-feedback-adjustment cycles in every single training session. Otherwise, the compounding doesn't happen. Any activity that throttles the number of these cycles cannot be described as deliberate practice.
Many heated debates in math education stem from these misinterpretations of deliberate practice. Mindless repetition, doing the same thing over and over again without making performance-improving adjustments, is not deliberate practice. Likewise, any activity that throttles the volume of action-feedback-adjustment cycles (e.g., excessively challenging problems, or think-pair-share type of stuff) is not deliberate practice.
Addendum 1: Worked examples are needed
Math gets hard for different students at different levels – it can be as early as high school algebra or as late as graduate-level algebraic topology – but everyone eventually reaches a level where things no longer feel obvious and they can't figure things out as quickly on the fly. If you're not yet at the edge of human knowledge, that's where worked examples and instructional scaffolding come in to keep you making fast progress.
Without worked examples, learners eventually reach a point where unguided problem-solving overwhelms their working memory and puts them in a state of cognitive overload. They feel frustrated, confused, and are unable to solve problems. And even before that point, even if a student is able to solve problems successfully without worked examples, it typically takes a lot longer, which throttles the volume of practice.
If you don't have worked examples and instructional scaffolding to help carry you through once math becomes hard for you, then every problem basically blows up into a research project for you. That's okay if you're a research mathematician (or maybe late-stage graduate student) at the edge of your field, but if you're a student who still has a ways to go before reaching the edge of human mathematical knowledge, then it's just less efficient, even if you have fun with it.
If you want to maximize how far you get in a talent domain, then you need to grab all the examples & problem-solving experiences in the direction that you're going, as quickly as possible, and then only once you reach the end of the road with known examples and problem-solving experiences, do you switch over to creative production. Creative production is a way less efficient way of moving forward so you want to save it for the end when it's the only way to continue moving forward.
(To be clear: this is not just my opinion, this is based on findings from Benjamin Bloom's research on talent development. This is the same Bloom who created Bloom's taxonomy, which many educators use as justification for having students spend a lot of time working on project – but that is actually misinterpreting Bloom's taxonomy in a way that is not aligned with Bloom's seminal work that came later in his career. I've written more about that here.)
Addendum 2: But how can you develop deep understanding if you use worked examples?
First of all: I'm not advocating for mindless mimicry here. There should be plenty of practice on theoretical foundations, including derivations, reasoning about the conditions under which a theorem might apply, etc. This is not inherently at odds with the idea of deliberate practice using worked examples & practice problems. It is trickier to construct worked examples & practice problems that meaningfully test learners on theoretical foundations, but it can be done.)
Second of all, when you continually layer advanced skills on top of existing skills, it forces you to deepen your understanding, really internalizing those existing skills and the ideas behind them. This is basically the idea of "structural integrity" in the context of knowledge.

When advanced features are built on top of a system, they sometimes fail in ways that reveal previously-unknown foundational weaknesses in the underlying structure. This forces engineers to fortify the underlying structure so that the system can accommodate new elements without compromising its integrity.

Fortifying the underlying structure often requires improving its organization and elegance, which, in the context of student knowledge, produces deep understanding and insight.

When the structural integrity of a system is increased, it also becomes easier to add more advanced features in general. In the same way, when the structural integrity of a student’s knowledge is increased, it becomes easier to assimilate new knowledge in general.


When you layer on advanced skills, it forces understanding. If there’s some level of understanding you're lacking in some component knowledge, you eventually get to a point where the lack of understanding prevents you from successfully learning more advanced skills.
For instance, there's no way that you can get through a legitimate calculus course without having a real understanding of algebra. In fact, many math students will tell you that calculus is what really deepened their understanding of algebra.
Addendum 3: For anyone who suggests that this answer does not apply to advanced mathematics (analysis, topology, abstract algebra, etc.)...
... I recognize that there's barely any empirical research into education at this level of math. But are you aware of any research where deliberate practice was not found to be the most efficient practice technique, in any talent domain? As far as I'm aware, no counterexamples have been found (though I'd be really interested to read about any if there's something I've missed).
Basically, it seems like there's a mountain of circumstantial empirical evidence (in both talent development & cognitive science research) suggesting that the superiority of deliberate practice would carry over to the setting of advanced mathematics. So in the absence of any contradictory research, why would we expect anything otherwise?
If you're a math professor, then I recognize that you have plenty of experience studying/teaching advanced mathematics, and if you claim that doesn't carry over into advanced math in your personal experience, then that's a claim worth considering. But at the same time, I do have some experience myself in studying/teaching advanced mathematics (not as much as you, but some), and in my experience, the superiority of deliberate practice is fully supported.
Just to name one example: last year, I tutored a student who was taking analysis at an elite university, and each problem set consisted of those "think really hard for a long period of time" problems. Things were going the way of a train wreck: despite her best efforts, she was spinning her wheels on these problems and making very little progress. Not only was she unable to solve the problems, but also, she was not noticeably improving any supporting knowledge by trying and failing to solve them.
What I ended up doing was engaging her in deliberate practice on all of the component knowledge that was being pulled together in each problem. Something like this (the following is non-exhaustive):

Deliberate Practice on Definitions: I give you a mathematical object and you tell me whether it meets the definition (and why or why not). Repeat over and over again increasing in difficulty. Okay, now suppose we remove some criterion from the definition. What's an object that didn't meet the original definition but does now after dropping that criterion? Repeat over and over dropping different criteria.

Deliberate Practice on Theorems: I give you a scenario and you tell me whether it meets the assumptions of the theorem. If so, you tell me specifically what else you know is true about the scenario, according to the theorem. Repeat over and over again increasing in difficulty. Okay, if this is a one-way implication, tell me some scenarios where the converse does not hold.


As soon as we took a step back from the homework problems and started doing that, she started making actual progress on her supporting knowledge. After enough cycles of deliberate practice, she'd re-attempt the homework problems, often solving them completely or at least getting a lot further before starting to spin her wheels again.
The result: her exam performance skyrocketed and she ended up finishing the course with an A.
What could have happened: without this deliberate practice intervention, she would have gotten a low grade in the course and possibly even dropped out of the major entirely.
(Note: Even after learning metacognitive techniques for thinking critically about definitions and theorems, she still required me to create deliberate practice problems for her by targeting weaknesses and selecting specific objects / scenarios to highlight key features & scaffold from easy to hard difficulty.
In general, a learner typically cannot construct their own deliberate practice experience without expert guidance since they are typically unable to construct information-rich & scaffolded practice problems, much less correctly identify their areas of weakness for targeted practice to begin with.
So, it would not be accurate to suggest that the student could carry out future deliberate practice on her own after learning metacognitive skills for parsing definitions/theorems, implying that the kinds of problems given to the student could be construed as effective for independent practice once those metacognitive skills were learned.)
Addendum 4: "Could you suggest some talent development / expertise literature in psychology? I'd greatly appreciate it."
I'd start with K. Anders Ericsson, the academic father of deliberate practice. His work is extensive. Here are some of my selections:

Ericsson, K. A. (2008). Deliberate practice and acquisition of expert performance: a general overview. Academic emergency medicine, 15(11), 988-994.
Ericsson, K. A. (2006). The influence of experience and deliberate practice on the development of superior expert performance. The Cambridge handbook of expertise and expert performance, 38(685-705), 2-2.
Ericsson, K. A. (2003). The acquisition of expert performance as problem solving: Construction and modification of mediating mechanisms through deliberate practice. The psychology of problem solving, 31-83.
Ericsson, K. A., Krampe, R. T., & Tesch-Römer, C. (1993). The role of deliberate practice in the acquisition of expert performance. Psychological review, 100(3), 363.

Some other references worth checking out, related to deliberate practice:

Anderson, J. R., Reder, L. M., Simon, H. A., Ericsson, K. A., & Glaser, R. (1998). Radical constructivism and cognitive psychology. Brookings papers on education policy, (1), 227-278. (See, especially, the comment by Ericsson starting on page 255)
Coughlan, E. K., Williams, A. M., McRobert, A. P., & Ford, P. R. (2014). How experts practice: A novel test of deliberate practice theory. Journal of Experimental Psychology: Learning, Memory, and Cognition, 40(2), 449.
Lehtinen, E., Hannula-Sormunen, M., McMullen, J., & Gruber, H. (2017). Cultivating mathematical skills: From drill-and-practice to deliberate practice. ZDM, 49, 625-636.
Plant, E. A., Ericsson, K. A., Hill, L., & Asberg, K. (2005). Why study time does not predict grade point average across college students: Implications of deliberate practice for academic performance. Contemporary educational psychology, 30(1), 96-116.
Reeves, W. R. (2014). Creativity as a learned skill: The role of deliberate practice in the development of creativity (Doctoral dissertation).

And some lighter reading:

Clear, J. The Beginner’s Guide to Deliberate Practice. JamesClear.com.
Ericsson, K. A., Prietula, M. J., & Cokely, E. T. (2007). The making of an expert. Harvard business review, 85(7/8), 114.
Parrish, S. The Ultimate Deliberate Practice Guide: How to Be the Best. FS.blog.

Oh, you probably also want to read about Bloom's 3-stage process of talent development that describes the striking commonalities Bloom discovered when studying the backgrounds of extremely successful individuals across a wide variety of fields.
The 3-stage process is the main thesis of Benjamin Bloom’s 1985 book Developing Talent in Young People. The stages are summarized well in the 2002 paper Role of the Elite Coach in the Development of Talent by Gordon Bloom.
Some other interesting reads from Benjamin Bloom on the topic of talent development:

Bloom, B. S., & Sosniak, L. A. (1981). Talent development vs. schooling. Educational Leadership, 39(2), 86-94.
Brandt, R. S. (1985). On Talent Development: A Conversation with Benjamin Bloom. Educational Leadership, 43(1), 33-35.
Bloom, B. S. (1986). Automaticity: "The Hands and Feet of Genius." Educational leadership, 43(5), 70-77.

Another reference worth checking out:

Luo, L., & Kiewra, K. A. (2021). Parents' roles in talent development. Gifted Education International, 37(1), 30-40.


Foundational skills you are thinking of probably include arithmetic, algebraic manipulations, setting up equations, and solving equations. But problem solving is also a foundational skill! So in addition to practicing setting up equations, practicing times tables, and practicing dividing fractions, you also want to practice problem solving. That's what challenge problems are for. If they are too hard, as is the case in OP's question, what one needs is easier challenge problems.

Not to mention, a (correctly targeted) challenge question can provide practice in the other foundational skills too, for example in the following way: If you need to calculate small test cases of the problem to get a feel for the problem, then you may be doing 10 or 20 or 30 fraction divisions as well as solving 10 or 20 or 30 algebraic equations while calculating those test cases.

I'm a bit skeptical of a few points in your answer: For instance, I see no way to ever learn a significant number of advanced mathematical concepts if you focus on a large number of problems each of which takes you two minutes to solve. The vast majority of homework problems that I've seen at university level take much longer than two minutes, and I strongly doubt that one could achieve the same effect by replacing them with a much larger number of much shorter problems.

Similarly, deliberate practice is certainly good for some skills in mathematics, but I have doubts how much it helps to generate deep understanding and intuition for a topic or a technique. In my experience, it is crucial for understanding and intuition that you do not only practice things that work, but that you get experience with what does not work and a feeeling for why it does not work. While a "high volume of action-feedback-adjustment cycles" will certainly expose you to many things that don't work, those things will always be quite close to the techniques that actually do work.

For instance, the following is quite common for math programmes in Germany. First year: real analysis in one and several variables; vector spaces and linear algebra over general fields (all with a focus on proofs); some "adjacent" topics, e.g. introduction to computer science and programming. Second year: measure and integration theory and/or ODE theory; stochastics (including general probability spaces); introduction to numerical mathematics and optimization; an algebra course, e.g. about group theory. How could this work if students mainly solved a huge amount of two-minutes problems?

@JochenGlueck: I share your reservations when it comes to more theoretical courses, although note that in some countries these will typically not be encountered until late undergraduate level if not beyond, so there is a lot of room in introductory calculus, linear algebra or differential equations courses (to give some common examples) for exercises for which deliberate practice is helpful. This may also occur in mathematics courses for engineering or other applications-focused disciplines.

@JW: Yes, agreed. I assume that Justin was mainly thinking about undergraduate studies in the US while writing the answer. I think it would be good to explicitly point out this context in the answer. And admittedly, I doubt that US undergraduate students enrolled in a calculus course are the target audience for a Soviet era Russian textbook called "Mathematical Analysis". So to sum up, I think the answer gives the impression to be more widely applicable than it actually is.

@JochenGlueck When I say "2 minute problems" I don't mean that as a hard cap. I just mean that you come into the problem with enough background knowledge that you can work 100% productively to complete it in a minimal amount of time. I agree that the minimal amount of time may increase as a student gets into proofs in more theoretical courses in late undergrad. But I doubt it's really necessary to go over, say, 5-10 minutes. Like, I can't imagine a scenario in which a student spends a full hour on a problem while working productively the whole time.

@JustinSkycak: E.g. for a functional analysis lecture, after discussing the spectrum and eigenvalues of an operator, a very typical exercise is "Consider the left shift on $\ell^2$ and determine its eigenvalues and its spectrum." To do it, one needs to use various results from the lecture, combined with a few computations, and one does not know in advance where precisely to start. Solving the problem easily takes 30 to 60 minutes, depending on whether you find an efficient approach quickly. You seem to assume that the time one spends on trying approaches that turn out not to work, [...]

[...] is lost or used non-productively; but I disagree - these failures teach a great deal about how the results from the lecture relate to each other and about how they can and how they can't be used. Splitting the problem into smaller subproblems is possible (and I sometimes do that) but when the pieces become so small that the path is always more or less clear, a lot of opportunity for learning is lost.

To give an extreme example: When I was a student, in the second half of my first year I took a course "Linear algebra 2". On one homework sheet, the lecturers defined the Fibonacci sequence $(f_n)$ recursively and the problem was: find an explicit formula for $(f_n)$. No hints, not even any comment on how this relates to linear algebra. I thought about it for many hours. I stared at the first 10 or so elements to find a pattern, failed, thought again, finally managed to write $(f_n)$ in terms of matrix powers, but didn't see how diagonalization can be used to compute the matrix powers. [...]

[...] When the lecturers gave us the solution, it was a relevation for me: (i) there can be patterns in sequences of integers that you just can't see with the bare eye; (ii) irrational numbers can be necessary to give a formula for a sequence of integers; (iii) matrices can be useful for problems involving only scalar numbers; (iv) diagonalization is a great tool to compute matrix powers. With a lot of hints and a clear path, I could have solved 10 such exercises, each of them broken down into several small pieces, in the same time - but no chance I would have learnt remotely as much.

Sorry, I noted just now that you edited your answer. Since you stress that your claims are backed-up by empirical research - I would be very interested to read empirical findings that back up your points in the context of advanced topics (say, functional analysis, measure theory, algebraic topology, etc). I've hardly ever seen empirical research results about education at this level and I am still skeptical that your claims apply in this context as they contradict my experience (as a student and as an educator) - but in case that I'm wrong I would be interested to read some research about it.

@JochenGlueck like you suggest, I'm not aware of any studies in mathematics that advanced. But, more generally, are you aware of any research where deliberate practice was not found to be the most efficient practice technique, in any talent domain? As far as I'm aware, no counterexamples have been found (though I'd be really interested to read about any if there's something I've missed).

[...] Basically, it seems like there's a mountain of circumstantial evidence (in both talent development & cognitive science research) suggesting the superiority of deliberate practice (DP) would carry over to the setting of advanced mathematics. So in the absence of any contradictory research, why would we expect anything otherwise?

[...] I recognize that you have plenty of experience studying/teaching advanced mathematics, so if you claim that DP doesn't carry over into advanced math, then that's a claim worth considering -- but I do have some experience myself (not as much as you, but some), and in my experience, the superiority of DP is fully supported.

Could you suggest some talent development/ expertise literature in psychology? I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

I can offer an alternative explanation for the anecdote in your Addendum 3. As an effective tutor you identified your student's lack of prerequisite skills that were causing her to be stuck: understanding definitions and theorem statements. (For an analysis class at an elite university where the typical homework is problems like these, the ability to parse definitions and theorems is surely a prerequisite.) Then you helped her develop those skills. After addressing it, she is now able to solve the problems.

@YinuoAn: Sure, I added some talent development / expertise literature for you in Addendum 4.

@YongyiChen: Not quite. Even after learning metacognitive techniques for thinking critically about definitions and theorems, she still required me to create deliberate practice problems for her by selecting specific objects and scenarios to highlight key features and scaffold from easy to hard difficulty. Construction of effective deliberate practice problems often requires expertise to begin with -- it's not just about metacognition.

@JustinSkycak Wait, I was not talking about metacognition. What you said in your reply agrees with what I said, that you created practice problems for her to practice understanding definition and theorem statements. In any case, the important part was that you even identified those areas of weakness. Deliberate practice would not help if the area of weakness was misidentified, or not known at all.

@YongyiChen: Got it, my bad, I thought you were suggesting that the student could carry out future deliberate practice on her own after learning metacognitive skills for parsing definitions/theorems, implying that the kinds of problems given to the student could be construed as effective for independent practice. I agree that a novice typically cannot do deliberate practice without expert guidance since they typically are unable to correctly identify their areas of weakness in the first place.

@JustinSkycak Yep, cheers!

With competition problems I always felt like I either saw the trick (or otherwise understood what to do), or I didn't. It might still take a while, but that had more to do with grinding through the still-necessary-after-the-trick calculations and double-checking for sign errors. Also, I was really never able to make myself site down for deliberate practice, unless someone else was making a competition of it. And even then, I could certainly lose to people who didn't get invited to write the competitions I did.

I don't know the research on this, but one argument for letting students get stuck sometimes is that in real life, one gets stuck sometimes, so it would be nice if school would prepare us for dealing with that experience.

@JochenGlueck I agree with your points, but I think the difference to this answer is mostly a question of degree. The 2 min problems, maybe 5-10 min max seem way too short for sufficiently advanced material. Graduate level maths courses in the US or lectures in pure maths in the German system will have problems in the 15-60 min range. Anything below that is trivial checking of definitions/ theorems that provides no learning. For math competition training you reach these time frames already for high school students.

The alternative view is that diving into the deep end forces you to backfill foundational knowledge.

@NeelSandell Sure, that can work out alright for a certain type of person, and maybe you're one of them. But in general, very few people are that type of person. For the vast, vast majority of people, diving into the deep end starts with excitement but quickly transitions to confusion, flailing, and ultimately quitting.

@JochenGlueck I note that the points you say you learned from the Fibonacci problem are facts and not skills. I have hypotheses on how struggling with a problem and then experiencing "insight" may help with the learning/retention of facts: creating retrieval cues, experiencing strong emotions in the moment of "revelation," attending to differences between the problem and past experiences, comparing strategies, etc. But I wonder if there are more efficient and/or effective ways to guide students through this process than the traditional "go struggle with this problem for a few hours” approach.

@JustinHancock: Maybe the concise wording I used makes those points sound a bit like facts, but I disagree that any of them is really about facts. For instance, regarding (iv), "diagonalization is a great tool to compute matrix powers" is, as a pure fact, pretty much useless. The point if of course that one is able to actually do it and that one recognizes when to do it, which are skills rather than facts. Similarly for (iii). Regarding (i): If you read the sentence "there can be patterns in sequences of integers that you just can't see with the bare eye" [...]

[...] as a factual statement, it is close to worthless because it's so utterly vague. If you make it more concrete, say, "the explicit formula for the Fibonacci numbers shows a pattern which is impossible to recognize with the bare eye", it becomes slightly better but, as a fact in itself, it still doesn't convey much insight. And indeed, this is what I'd say (i) is really about: it's neither a fact nor a skill, it is an insight - which is not so much the fact itself, but rather an intuition about the background and the meaning of this fact and its relation to other facts. Same for (ii).

@JochenGlueck By "facts" I meant declarative knowledge to be recalled. When a student looks at a linear recurrence, my goal is that they can recall the fact/understanding/insight that "matrices can be used to solve linear recurrences," then fluently perform practiced skills. Aha! moments can improve recall of declarative knowledge, and my point was that we should consider how to best guide students to insight and to learning from failed approaches. Struggle can be productive, but it often is not, especially without guidance.

I'm broadly in agreement with Skycak's answer (relevance of drill, progressive [slow] difficulty increases), but will give a few practical pieces of advice.

Look at a few texts before jumping into one.  Go to an academic library or a professor's office and actually look at some.

For self-studying (it's implicit from your choice process), you need an easy book even MORE than for a regular class.  Because the major danger in self study is GIVING UP. (Be very wary of some of the advice on Reddit, SE, etc. pushing the hardest textbooks.  The Rudin-pushers, the Spivak-pushers.)

You need to do drill and have at least some easy problems.  Look at the numbered problems...do they have easy, middle, hard sections?  Are there any obviously reinforcing knowledge type questions?  Or are they all ball busters?  Note that as courses get harder, textbooks get worse at having a good selection of training problems.  I have seen this often in the natural sciences--intro courses in chemistry or physics are well constructed pedagogically.  Graduate textbooks are not.  This is not because some magic switch has changed in the literal trained mammals.  I have some ideas why this happens (lower market size, less corrective measure for poor instruction, writers more interested in impressing colleagues and avoiding errors than in teaching, etc.)  But just realize it is common.  At real analysis, you're sort of part way up that curve of pedagogy getting worse as material gets harder.  But in a course where "struggle with it" is emphasized (too much IMO).

You need answers to the problems.  You need a source of feedback...and rapid feedback.  (Not waiting a day or longer for responses from SE or a tutor.  Nothing wrong with that as one more layer of help...but for regular problems, you need some more rapid feedback.)  At a minimum answers...even better is worked solutions.  But usually the answer in concert with the text source is enough...and you can go to the web with questions on the very small number that still confuse you.  So either in the text...or with a key or solution manual that you can obtain.  This will substantially reduce the choices (as the market eschews having the answers available...for...reasons.)

If possible, "programmed instruction" or "programmed learning" is an outstanding way of doing self-study of any topic.  You get rapid feedback and little acts of engagement, while reading the text.  Books like this are rare and mostly written in the 60s/70s...but if you find one, it is a treasure.

For analysis, specifically, there is a market for easier textbooks, if you search you will find some.

There is also a (small) market for drill materials and solutions in analysis.  So you can actually look for texts called "problems in analysis" (or similar).

(Edit, out of order)  Look at the pre-reqs in the preface.  Or in the problems.  If the book expects you to know some courses you haven't had, ditch the book. I've had a similar experience to you with the differential geometry experience.  In my case, it was a complex analysis textbook, where the very first set of problems expected you know some series evaluation techniques from real analysis (that I had not had).  Just put a book like that on the side and buy another one.



I guess at a certain point, grad students don't need a ton of exercises because just understanding the proofs line-by-line and filling in all the gaps becomes its own exercise. But I agree there's a gap in the middle (advanced undergrad/early grad stage) where most students aren't yet self-directing enough to learn in that way, but the books don't have enough of the exercises that would help.

When writing a textbook, the key is to know your audience and make it clear who that audience is, including expected background and aims. State it in the preface and, if you have any control over what's on the back cover, state it briefly there too. It can be tricky, though, to get right - because of your own assumptions and blind spots, and because prospective readers may come from a different country or years/decades in the future.
When choosing a textbook for yourself, keep the above in mind and, if at all possible, read the preface and skim through the book before purchasing or borrowing it. Be prepared to try out several books on a topic - for instance, there are many books on mathematical analysis of widely-varying levels of difficulty and style: just compare Rudin with Pugh with Abbott with Cummings. If you find a book too easy or too hard (or otherwise not to your taste) after spending at least some tens of hours giving it a try, move on to another one. I'm afraid there's just a certain amount of trial and error involved.
Also, if you are studying without an instructor/tutor and regular assignments or practice sessions, you'll need to find other ways to check your understanding. So, consider books with solutions or at least hints available for a reasonable number of problems. This can be in the book itself or in a separate solutions manual or problem book. (For an example of the latter at an advanced level, see T.Y. Lam's Exercises in Classical Ring Theory to accompany his A First Course in Noncommutative Rings.) Otherwise, you'll have to find ways to check your own work for correctness. This is  easier said than done, although it can be useful to develop a toolkit of common checks. See Teaching students to find and correct their own errors for some examples focusing on calculations. For checking proofs, see Teaching students how to check the validity of their proofs.

If you're looking for some more accessible analysis texts, you should look at Abbott and Jay Cummings' books. Also of you're in the US, you should consider dual enrollment at your state's flagship university if possible, or some other institutions where you can benefit from a teacher, have external validation for your studies, and potentially gain some very valuable letters of recommendation. Other avenues for college admissions could be individual math competitions like the AMC/USAMTS, or a group activity like organizing other homeschoolers to form a math team for the purpose of participating in team-based math competitions.
